# Recover Hibernate connection

Tags: java, hibernate

Does anybody know a way to reestablish/retry again hibernate connection. I mean for example: the remote DB is down and I start my application. Hibernate is not able to establish a connection. it fails. But the application is not closed. Is there a way to say hibernate to try one more time to establish a connecton?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19):

You should really go for C3P0 connection pooling: http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#hibernate-specific

There is a section in C3P0 documentation on that subject: http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#configuring_recovery

First you have to properly configure c3p0, which in case of using hibernate must happen in c3p0.properties file.

In your c3p0.properties put these properties to retry to reconnect indefinitely every 3 seconds when database is down:

```
c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts = 0
c3p0.acquireRetryDelay = 3000
c3p0.breakAfterAcquireFailure = false
```

Also, to avoid broken connections lying in your pool indefinitely, use connection age management:

```
c3p0.maxConnectionAge = 6000
c3p0.maxIdleTime = 6000
c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections = 1800
c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod = 3600
```

These may be quite expensive, but helpful if above is not enough:

```
c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout = true
c3p0.preferredTestQuery = SELECT 1;
```

You may also want to check for connection leaks which prevent recovery:

```
c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces = true
```

And finally, make sure that C3P0 is hooked with hibernate correctly, enable debug logging for "com.mchange" package and see if C3P0 tells you anything about itself. It should state configuration properties which are loaded, so see if it's all there.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

C3P0 is the internal connection-pool implementation for hibernate.

Add "hibernate.connection.provider_class = org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider"
in hibernate properties file. Create a file c3p0.properties setting the parameters accordingly. This file & c3p0-x.jar must be in classpath.

**c3p0.properties**

- **c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod** : If this is a number greater than 0, c3p0 will test all idle, pooled but unchecked-out connections, every this number of seconds.
- **c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout** : Use only if necessary. Expensive. If true, an operation will be performed at every connection checkout to verify that the connection is valid. Better choice: verify connections periodically using idleConnectionTestPeriod.

There are several other properties that can be configured in hibernate.properties & c3p0.properties.

Comment: Yes this was my first step. But it did not work. I did all what you are talking about but without result. C3p0 connection pool tester is not called if DB is down. If DB is working and I started the application when tester is working as well and I see that it is able to check the connection status. But I want to know what to do in case if DB is down. I meant the application tried to crete a connection pool but without succes, after sometime itwill try to do it one more time.

Comment: If you DB is down, it will retry up to acquireRetryAttempts times, with a delay of acquireRetryDelay between each attempt & after that will probably result in exception.

Comment: Yes this is what I see. Hibernate tries to reconnect acquireRetryAttempts  times with acquireRetryDelay delay but after there is no exception. And I don't understand how to understand is hibernate connected or not to DB.

Comment: Implement ConnectionTester for connection validation - http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/index.html & handle exception there. Else you have to go through c3p0 implementation & build your own PooledDataSource, see documentation - http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html

Answer (score 0):

May be, you try to call method **.getCurrentSession()** instead **.openSession()**?

If connection falls you must establish new one.

I hope this helps.